# How to add a dot/point in a plotly scatterplot

Tags: python, plotly

I already have a scatterplot (interactive) made with plotly, and I would like to add one dot, not necessarily interactive, in a specific coordinate (to mark the median). How can I add it?

```
fig = px.scatter(df_b,
                x="EAD", 
                y="RAR",
                size="Margen_bruto",
                hover_name="Cliente",
                hover_data={'EAD': ':.0f', 'RAR': ':.0%', 'Margen_bruto': ':.0f'},
                size_max=30,
                trendline='lowess',
                trendline_color_override='black',
                trendline_scope='overall',
                title="BÉLGICA dic 2019 - 46 clientes")
```

I've already used functions like `fig.add_annotation` and `fig.add_hline` to add text and lines to my graph, but I can't seem to be able to add just one point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to add it, but it can be added with add_scatter(); the data required for xy must be a list or an array, so the xy value should be a list. Since you did not provide any data, I adapted your code from the [example](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#linear-regression-and-other-trendlines) in the reference.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x="total_bill",
                 y="tip",
                 trendline="lowess",
                 trendline_color_override='black',
                 trendline_scope='overall',
                )
fig.add_scatter(x=[df['total_bill'].median()],
                y=[df['tip'].median()],
                marker=dict(
                    color='red',
                    size=10
                ),
               name='median')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I have a further question. The hover data over the median point marks two data (EAD and RAR). I would like to put the RAR as a percentage and the EAD as a number without decimals. How can I do that?

Comment: Since your data is unknown, I will comment with my response that the hover data displayed in the current response shows the median value of each. If you want to customize it further with a hover template, you can do so with the following code. `fig.add_scatter(x=[df['total_bill'].median()], y=[df['tip'].median()],                hovertemplate='total_bill_median: %{x}<br>tip: %{y}',...)`

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on r-begginners' answer.

From [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/):

> Regardless of how a graph object figure was constructed, it can be updated by adding additional traces to it and modifying its properties.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x="total_bill",
                 y="tip",
                 trendline="lowess",
                 trendline_color_override='black')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20], y=[10], marker_symbol='x', marker_size=15))
```

And the result:
[image: Plot]

`add_scatter` is a convenience method provided by plotly:

> As an alternative to the add_trace() method, graph object figures have a family of methods of the form add_{trace} (where {trace} is the name of a trace type) for constructing and adding traces of each trace type.

It is certainly a more readable option, but I felt it is helpful to know about how traces are handled nonetheless.